# How to get the Azure SQL maximum database limit?

Tags: sql-server, azure

We are 3rd party for the customer, and we implement the web application on the top of their ERP data. They migrated to Azure SQL (cloud) about 4 years ago. Currently, they observe performance problems, and it seems to be caused by being near the limit of the database size. I am not able to tell **what is the actual size limit applied to the application database**.

**SSMS:** When using Database Properties from the SSMS console, it shows:

[image: Query Store pie chart]

When looking at the General tab it shows Size and Size Available

[image: the General tab]

The Configure SLO tab say the maximum size 14 GB:

[image: Configure SLO]

**Azure SQL console:** However, when talking to their ERP implementor, their database administrator says, it should be OK.

[image: Azure Console]

So, there are apparently two limits like 50 GB and 14 GB. Which of the limits applies to the web application that accesses the application database? Is the limit almost reached, or the SSMS shows a distorted view? Can that be the reason for the observed problems (like extremely slow SQL operations outside the set timeout)?

Comment: I can confirm that the Max Size you see on the SLO screen is the currently allocated size of the database.  Not necessarily how much data is in there, but how much Azure has allocated that specific database.  The max size that the custom sent you is the configured absolute max size.  Have you looked at the output of sys.dm_db_resource_stats to see if there is contention for resources?

Comment: @JonathanFite: Thanks for the information. No, I have not looked into the stats. Frankly, I am not that good in the database administration. Also, it seems I have no permissions to use the view (`VIEW DATABASE PERFORMANCE STATE permission denied in database 'master'... The user does not have permission to perform this action.`). And I am afraid, that their ERP-system administrator may not know what should be done. What should I ask him to do? Please, add it as the comment (to be accepted).

Comment: Size of the database is rarely the root cause of performance problems. The issue is likely poor architectural design, poor application / query design, or possibly severely under-provisioned hardware, since this started happening after going to the cloud. But I'd bet my money on one of the former two. Also, 14 GB or even 50 GB is a tiny database size, so that's surely not your issue. It's not clear if the performance problems you refer to are from their native queries / application or from your web application. Either way, some concrete query information e.g. execution plans is needed to debug.

Comment: S0 is the bottom possible choice outside of basic. To quote the docs, "The Standard S0, S1 and S2 tiers provide less than one vCore (CPU). For resource-intensive workloads, a service tier of S3 or greater is recommended." Given this is PaaS, it's almost entirely, at this point, the fact that a terrible SLO was chosen. You can enable metrics in Azure and take a look but it has almost no DTUs, max of 10, and is sub-core. It'd be faster to run this on a laptop from 2008.

Comment: ^Welp there's your answer: *severely under-provisioned hardware*.